# Search in table with checkbox in java swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

[image]

Can anyone help me?

I try to use key released for searching in the table with check box in java swing, but when I type a character the check box disappears

I use this code for the key released:

```
Jtable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(null, new Object[]{"Name","code","section","credit","type","hours","semestre","null"}));
```

How can I keep the check box when I search for a value in this table?????

Comment: So you're trying to set the checkmark for matching elements from the search field?

Comment: I think you are trying to "filter" the table based on the text entered into the text field. If so, you should NOT be using a KeyListener. Instead you should be using a `DocumentFilter`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for a complete working example that filters the data in the table.

Comment: Thanks❤️I found the solution using key released: String search =jtextfield.getText();  TableRowSorter tr = new TableRowSorter(model);    Jtable.setRowSorter(tr);    tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(search));

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `KeyListener` on a text component, it's just an inappropriate usage.

Instead, use `DocumentListener` on the underlying `Document`, for example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTable table;
        private JTextField searchField;
        private SubjectTableModel tableModel;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JPanel searchPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            searchField = new JTextField(20);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(8, 8, 8, 8);

            searchPanel.add(new JLabel("Enter Value to Search:"), gbc);

            gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.gridx++;
            searchPanel.add(searchField, gbc);

            add(searchPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            List<SubjectTabelItem> items = new ArrayList<>(25);
            items.add(new SubjectTabelItem("Chemistry", "CH3305", "English", 6, "Mandatory", 20, "S3"));
            items.add(new SubjectTabelItem("Data", "I2206", "French", 5, "Mandatory", 50, "S4"));
            items.add(new SubjectTabelItem("Java", "I2211", "French", 5, "Mandatory", 45, "S4"));
            items.add(new SubjectTabelItem("Theorie", "Th3306", "French", 6, "Optional", 20, "S3"));
            items.add(new SubjectTabelItem("Arabic", "A1265", "French", 3, "Optional", 20, "S4"));
            items.add(new SubjectTabelItem("Html", "H102", "English", 4, "Mandatory", 12, "S1"));
            items.add(new SubjectTabelItem("Php", "PI3301", "English", 3, "Mandatory", 25, "S3"));
            items.add(new SubjectTabelItem("Assembly", "I3564", "English", 3, "Optional", 20, "S5"));
            items.add(new SubjectTabelItem("Go", "I1234", "English", 3, "Mandatory", 20, "S5"));

            tableModel = new SubjectTableModel(items);
            table = new JTable(tableModel);
            add(new JScrollPane(table));

            searchField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

                protected void process(DocumentEvent e) {
                    try {
                        Document document = e.getDocument();
                        String text = document.getText(0, document.getLength());
                        find(text);
                    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    process(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    process(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    process(e);
                }

            });
        }

        protected void find(String text) {
            tableModel.highlight(text);
        }

    }

    public class Stubject {

        private String name;
        private String code;
        private String section;
        private int credit;
        private String type;
        private int hours;
        private String semestre;

        public Stubject(String name, String code, String section, int credit, String type, int hours, String semestre) {
            this.name = name;
            this.code = code;
            this.section = section;
            this.credit = credit;
            this.type = type;
            this.hours = hours;
            this.semestre = semestre;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        public String getSection() {
            return section;
        }

        public int getCredit() {
            return credit;
        }

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public int getHours() {
            return hours;
        }

        public String getSemestre() {
            return semestre;
        }

    }

    public class SubjectTabelItem extends Stubject {

        private boolean selected = false;

        public SubjectTabelItem(String name, String code, String section, int credit, String type, int hours, String semestre) {
            super(name, code, section, credit, type, hours, semestre);
        }

        public boolean isSelected() {
            return selected;
        }

        public void setSelected(boolean isSelected) {
            this.selected = isSelected;
        }

    }

    public class SubjectTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<SubjectTabelItem> items;
        private String[] columnNames = new String[]{
            "Name",
            "Code",
            "Section",
            "Credit",
            "Type",
            "Hours",
            "Semestre",
            ""
        };

        public SubjectTableModel(List<SubjectTabelItem> items) {
            this.items = items;
        }

        public void setItems(List<SubjectTabelItem> items) {
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return columnNames[column];
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 4:
                case 6:
                    return String.class;

                case 3:
                case 5:
                    return Integer.class;

                case 7:
                    return Boolean.class;
            }

            return String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            SubjectTabelItem item = items.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    return item.getName();
                case 1:
                    return item.getCode();
                case 2:
                    return item.getSection();
                case 3:
                    return item.getCredit();
                case 4:
                    return item.getType();
                case 5:
                    return item.getHours();
                case 6:
                    return item.getSemestre();
                case 7:
                    return item.isSelected();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            SubjectTabelItem item = items.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 7:
                    if (aValue instanceof Boolean) {
                        boolean selected = (boolean) aValue;
                        if (selected != item.isSelected()) {
                            item.setSelected(selected);
                            fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void highlight(String text) {
            String lowerCased = text.toLowerCase();
            for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++) {
                SubjectTabelItem item = items.get(row);
                if (item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCased)) {
                    setValueAt(true, row, 7);
                } else {
                    setValueAt(false, row, 7);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See [How to Write a Document Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more details